# How to bless folder as bootable snapshot in macOS 12.3.1 on an Apple Silicon device?

Tags: mac, mount

I just updated my Apple Silicon Mac to macOS 12.3.1. Before I used to be able to delete system apps by mounting an APFS drive by using the following command:

```
sudo mount -o nobrowse -t apfs /dev/disk3s1 ~/mount
```

Then bless the folder as a bootable snapshot using:

```
sudo bless --folder "$HOME/mount/System/Library/CoreServices/" --bootefi --create-snapshot
```

But now I get this error:

```
bless: The 'folder' option is only supported for external media on Apple Silicon devices.
```

Does anyone know if the command changed and how to do it now?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After various random attempts I ended up figuring out the correct command. Hope this helps others who ran into the same issue.

```
sudo bless --mount "$HOME/mount/System/Library/CoreServices/" --setBoot --create-snapshot
```

Comment: I've tried to follow the outdated instructions on https://nektony.com/how-to/uninstall-default-apple-apps-on-mac and when that failed tried your bless command. Everything seemed fine, even after reboot. However when i tried to `csrutil enable` it reverted back to the old snapshot with all the apps installed. Any suggestions?

Comment: @jimbolino Im pretty sure if you re-enable system integrity then it removes your custom snapshot. The only way to keep it persisted is to leave system integrity disabled.

Comment: It's odd that this works.  On the manpage, the entry for  --setBoot says: "... This is not supported on Apple Silicon based systems."  ****, Apple!?  AND later on it shows this option usage for Apple Silicon based systems.  Schitzo!

Comment: Seems like the man page might be saying `--setBoot` isn't supported on Apple Silicon in File/Folder Mode but apparently is in Device and Mount modes. Because I've [also confirmed the only difference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73422893/14974911) between Intel and Apple Silicon appears to be `--folder` versus `--mount` flags.

Comment: @Jimbolino Yep, Jordan is right, I can confirm that [re-enabling SSV or even just SIP, or allowing any OS update](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73422893/14974911) will revert changes back to the original Apple-sanctioned version of the system volume. So apparently can't *both* protect system integrity *and* choose not to have e.g. Apple Music and News...which was always unfortunate but is now excessive, given all the preinstalled "extras" that can't be removed without disabling basic security features. As if the Chess, Podcasts, etc. apps are somehow "integral" to the operating system.